# Safely transport SecretKey for encryption/decryption of Password

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, password-encryption, secret-key

I am thinking about using ChaCha20-Poly1305 to encrypt/decrypt a password (I need to encrypt/decrypt cannot only hash). But, to use this algorithm we are required to use a Secret Key. However, this is a problem because I am encrypting/decrypting the user's password on their device, so in my DB I just store their encrypted password.

The problem with it, is if the user uninstall my app from their phone or change to a new phone, I would need the same secret key to be able to decrypt the user's password again.

My question is: How do I safely transfer and store this secret key ?

Also, please let me know if you have better alternatives for my problem, such as different encryption algorithm or methods.

Here is a code example with the SecretKey object that I've mentioned:

```
package com.javainterviewpoint;

import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class ChaCha20Poly1305Example
{
    static String plainText = "This is a plain text which will be encrypted by ChaCha20 Poly1305 Algorithm";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("ChaCha20");
        keyGenerator.init(256);

        // Generate Key
        SecretKey key = keyGenerator.generateKey();

        System.out.println("Original Text  : " + plainText);

        byte[] cipherText = encrypt(plainText.getBytes(), key);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Text : " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText));

        String decryptedText = decrypt(cipherText, key);
        System.out.println("DeCrypted Text : " + decryptedText);

    }

    public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] plaintext, SecretKey key) throws Exception
    {
        byte[] nonceBytes = new byte[12];

        // Get Cipher Instance
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("ChaCha20-Poly1305/None/NoPadding");
        
        // Create IvParamterSpec
        AlgorithmParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(nonceBytes);

        // Create SecretKeySpec
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getEncoded(), "ChaCha20");

        // Initialize Cipher for ENCRYPT_MODE
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivParameterSpec);

        // Perform Encryption
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);

        return cipherText;
    }

    public static String decrypt(byte[] cipherText, SecretKey key) throws Exception
    {
        byte[] nonceBytes = new byte[12];

        // Get Cipher Instance
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("ChaCha20-Poly1305/None/NoPadding");

        // Create IvParamterSpec
        AlgorithmParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(nonceBytes);
                
        // Create SecretKeySpec
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getEncoded(), "ChaCha20");

        // Initialize Cipher for DECRYPT_MODE
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivParameterSpec);

        // Perform Decryption
        byte[] decryptedText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);

        return new String(decryptedText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply have them re-enter their password whenever they install or re-install your app?

Answer (score -1):

For symmetric encryption and decryption, a best practice is use a MASTER KEY which is fixed string or has a fixed algorithm which just you know how to generate it.
You must use this MASTER KEY for encryption and decryption all other keys (name WORKING KEYS) to encrypt/decrypt real data.

If your device has a secure area which you can save your keys safely, you must inject master key on it by another device or by communicating with a server. If it has not, you are in RISK for disclosing keys.

However, if you are the only programmer of the app, you can use a fixed algorithm to generate MASTER key. For example `hash(xor(` of `1c1c1c` with the ID of the device. Now, the device can send a request for getting working keys (by sending its id and mac-block which is encrypted by master key) to a server and you give back the right working keys.

This scenario use in payments by ISO-8583.

Comment: A master key would be trivial to extract from an app.

Comment: In PCI standard, Master key stored on device not app. It is impossible to extract it from PED. However, if device doesn't have PED, it must use an algorithm to generate key, not a KEY.

Comment: What you call "master key" is itself a derived key. It's derived from the hard coded key "1c1c1c" and the device ID. It doesn't matter where this key is stored, because it can be trivially computed.

Comment: @Peter, The Master key must be injected by another device and there is massive methods to prevent disclosure! However, I said if you don't have another device to inject and you are the only programmer of the device you can do this instead of hard-coding the Master key. Of-course need sophisticated algorithm with Salting key to do that.